# Bell frequently sounds when editing vimrc

Tags: vim

The terminal bell frequently sounds in my `.vimrc` when it should not, including when I'm typing comments. What sorts of issues can typically cause this problem?

I have no idea where to start, and so am unsure what code to include, but here is a link to my `.vimrc`: https://github.com/adc17/.adc17/blob/master/vimrc. If there's any particular info you need about my configuration, feel free to ask and I'll post the relevant snippet.

Comment: A first step is to run vim without plugins, `vim -u NONE` and see if you can reproduce the bell problem

Comment: That's a much more complicated rc file than what I was expecting. Seeing it, my recommendation is to use a bifurcation method iteratively until you find the part of the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: Vim's plugin system, and the Vim plugin ecosystem, are also very bad. It's likely a plugin is causing the problem, or worse, some plugins are conflicting. You can comment out your pathogen lines and start vim until you don't hear the bell

Comment: Additionally, you can run `:messages` and see if there's any obvious errors

Comment: @AndyRay thanks, looks like it's a plugin. I'll uncomment them one by one and see if that finds the one responsible.

Comment: It was a plugin called `vim-mucomplete`, and I found an option to stop the ringing. Thanks for your help—it didn't occur to me that the problem was a plugin.

Comment: You can add your own answer to the question so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a plugin called vim-mucomplete, and I found an option to stop the ringing (`set belloff+=ctrlg`). Thanks to the commenters for their help—for some reason it didn't occur to me that the problem was a plugin.